# Gradient of tensor expressions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, machine-learning, tensors

I would like to compute gradients of tensor expressions without having to instantiate particular tensors and for arbitrary sizes.

**Example 1** :
For example, let's say I want to minimize $C=\sum_j(\sum_i M_{ij}X_i-Y_i)^2$ where $M$ is a matrix and $X$ and $Y$ are vectors, I would compute the gradient
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial X_k}=2\sum_jM_{kj}\left(\sum_i M_{ij}X_i-Y_j\right).$$

Of course I can compute this trivial one by hand. But what if I had a much more complicated expression with tensors of higher dimension?

**Example 2** :Consider the covariance matrix:
$$q_{jk}=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_i \left(x_{ij}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_l x_{lj}\right)\left(x_{ik}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_l x_{lk}\right)$$
How can I compute its gradient with respect to the data
$\frac{\partial q_{ik}}{\partial x_{mn}}$ ? This is a rank 4 tensor so I would like the result to be fully symbolic, i.e not for a particular range of indices but with symbolic indices.

How can I use Mathematica to compute such expressions ?

Comment: Perhaps an example of such a more complicated case could help.

Comment: @MarcoB I have edited the question with a more complicated example

Answer (score 1):

You may do this elementwise like e.g.:

```
n = 3;
xs = Array[x, n];
ys = Array[y, n];
ms = Array[m, {n, n}];
c = Total[(xs . ms - ys)^2];
D[c, {ys}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to do this in some more general notation without having to specify n=.. ?